# how to use this javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code for login and signup page i dont know how to use this code with html page
the CSS and HTML are working fine but the page doesnt use this code
i tried placing this code in script tag in head section but doesnt work

```
       $('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {

          var $this = $(this),
              label = $this.prev('label');

             if (e.type === 'keyup') {
        if ($this.val() === '') {
        label.removeClass('active highlight');
           } else {
         label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
          } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
            if( $this.val() === '' ) {
        label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
        } else {
        label.removeClass('highlight');   
        }   
        } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

          if( $this.val() === '' ) {
        label.removeClass('highlight'); 
        } 
       else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
        label.addClass('highlight');
        }
      }

        });

           $('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

        target = $(this).attr('href');

         $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

          $(target).fadeIn(600);

           });
```

Comment: Did you wrap this in `$(function() { //your code... });`?

Comment: @Arg0n id didnot do as you said because i'm new to javascript and still trying to learn but all i want is full working code so that i can use in my project thanks

Comment: Then try it... Place the code where '//your code...' is.

Comment: @Arg0n [link](http://codepen.io/ehermanson/pen/KwKWEv)  here is the link of all scripts i'm trying to use can you provide me code so that i can directly use because i'm still learning and i cant understand completely

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXmXVb

Comment: @Arg0n Thank you so much it works,i'm happy because i learned a new thing thank you !!!!

Comment: Added an answer, please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code inside `$(function() { //your code });` and it will execute after the `document` has loaded (document ready).